# No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, path, environment-variables

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10.

So, I just uploaded the Android Studio from the [site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio). 
After that I unpacked the zip file.
Went to **android-studio/bin** and found **studio.sh**.
Sit permission to be executed `chmod +x studio.sh`.
Ran the file to install with this line: `./studio.sh`.
Then I had the error

```
No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

I have already netbeans installed. I just ran the instalation package file [JDK + Netbeans](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html), so it was supposed to have java environments variables sit.

If I run `pintenv` the **PATH** environment variable do not hold the path to java. This is what I have:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

So, how can I find the location where Java was installed? I could set the PATH variable  manually.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried doing w.e. it may be just maybe... `sudo apt-get install default-jre`

Comment: hi 3kings. It doesn't wok.

Comment: Try clicking on `studio.sh`. IIRC it was easier to set up that way.

Comment: Hi Lauriel, nope. I got a Erro "File ....   could not be opened"

Comment: @zwitterion Look up on how to update java alternatives on linux. Should give you a simple command to run i think that would fix the problem. Or you just simply need to download jdk (.zip) and point your path inside the bin folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had very simmilar problem, I had all JAVA_HOME and other things done but I forget to set below lines in terminal:

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java 100
update-alternatives --config java